# ReactJS Form data not correct

Tags: reactjs

Noob here, I have a form that displays the data correctly when passed the props. Check, working fine. I want the "Edit" button to (temporarily) alert the data with changes. In the end the data will be saved. Saving the data is not problem.

When I first click the Edit button I get an empty array. I click again I get the correct data with changes I made...

Im just kinda stuck...Thanks!

Cant paste code so here's a link

[Code for SingleBook.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b70hC8QY6a0je9C2GntgshMaGkG5TovP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: use [markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to add the code snipped to your question:

Comment: Thanks! I do need to pay more attention...

Comment: You can still edit your question and add the code snippet ;) if, for some reason, the link is broken the original question cannot be understood anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `setState` is kinda async and you are not waiting for it. Checkout the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.

But it is possible to provide a callback:

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

Change your code to something like this (code not tested):

```
setBookState = (e, item) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    title: item.title,
    author: '',
    subject:'',
    descriptionOrsummary: '',
    errors: {},
    ...item
  }, () => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state))
    console.log(this.state)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. So within that callback it would be okay to verify and save data?

Comment: Please also mark the answer as accepted then. Regarding your question: With "save" you mean saving it to state or submitting it to the server? If you talk about submitting then I would suggest to add an `onSubmit` callback to your form instead of your current solution. But if you want to keep it like this, then yes, that is probably a good place. Also consider using a framework that helps you with form management such as [redux form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/) (if you are using redux) or [final form](https://github.com/final-form/final-form) (just react). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I will use onSubmit. I have all that part pretty much figured out...Thanks again!

Comment: glad I could help