# React Parent component checkbox state updates with one step delay

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "./Button";

export class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbers: [],
      disabled: false
    };

    this.setNum = this.setNum.bind(this);
  }

  setNum(num) {
    if (!this.state.numbers.includes(num)) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        numbers: [...prevState.numbers, num]
      }));
    } else if (this.state.numbers.includes(num)) {
      let nums = [...this.state.numbers];
      let index = nums.indexOf(num);
      nums.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ numbers: nums });
      console.log(this.state.numbers);
    }
    if (this.state.numbers.length >= 4) {
      this.setState({ disabled: true });
    } else if (this.state.numbers.length < 4) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board-container">
        <div className="board">
          <div className="row">
            <Button
              id="1"
              numbers={this.state.numbers}
              onChange={this.setNum}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            />
            <Button
              id="2"
              numbers={this.state.numbers}
              onChange={this.setNum}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            />
            <Button
              id="3"
              numbers={this.state.numbers}
              onChange={this.setNum}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            />
            <Button
              id="4"
              numbers={this.state.numbers}
              onChange={this.setNum}
              disabled={this.state.disabled}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

... and a Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
    });
    var num = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(num);
  }

  render() {
    const { isChecked } = this.state;

    if (isChecked === true) {
      var bgColor = "#f2355b";
    } else {
      bgColor = "#f7f7f7";
    }

    let disabled = this.props.disabled;

    if (this.props.numbers.includes(this.props.id)) {
      disabled = false;
    }

    return (
      <div className="number-container" id="checkboxes">
        <label
          className={!isChecked && disabled === false ? "num" : "checked-num"}
          style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}
        >
          {" "}
          {this.props.id}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={this.props.id}
            value={this.props.id}
            id={this.props.id}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            checked={isChecked}
            disabled={disabled}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever any Button component is clicked, the Parent component gets the child Button's `id` value and puts it into its `numbers` state array. Whenever a Button is unchecked, the Parent updates is `numbers` state by removing the `id` of the child Button.

If my code is right, the expected behavior is whenever a `Button` checkbox is clicked, the Parent numbers state will be updated immediately (adding or removing a number). However, it always updates with one step lag behind.

I know, that the issue is dealing with the React states not being updated instantly, and I've checked similar issues on Stackoverflow. The problem is that I can't figure it out how to make this two components interact with each other in a proper way. What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: setState is asynchronous. your console.log is executed before the state change has been propagated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52690082/2477619

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I know the issue, but can't understand how to fix it when I have two components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are three screenshots from codesandbox

If you want to play with it please find the link https://codesandbox.io/s/w2q8ypnxjw

What I did was, I basically copied and pasted your code and updated setNum function to reflect the changes [Think-Twice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6903497/think-twice) suggested

```
  setNum(num) {
    if (!this.state.numbers.includes(num)) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          numbers: [...prevState.numbers, num]
        }),
        () => {
          console.log("state logged inside if", this.state.numbers);
        }
      );
    } else if (this.state.numbers.includes(num)) {
      let nums = [...this.state.numbers];
      let index = nums.indexOf(num);
      nums.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ numbers: nums }, () => {
        console.log("state logged inside else if", this.state.numbers);
      });
    }
    if (this.state.numbers.length >= 4) {
      this.setState({ disabled: true });
    } else if (this.state.numbers.length < 4) {
      this.setState({ disabled: false });
    }
  }
```

So before going further let's quickly address a couple of things regarding to React and setState

1. As [B12Toaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2477619/b12toaster) mentioned and provided a link which contains a
   quote from official documentation

   > setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
   >   batch or defer the update until later.

   Think-Twice's also points out that by stating

   > Basically setState is asynchronous in React. When you modify a value
   >   using setState you will be able to see the updated value only in
   >   render..

   So if you want to see the immediate state change in a place which
   you trigger setState, you can make use of a call back function as
   such `setState(updater[, callback])`
2. There are two approaches when it comes to and updater with setState,
   you could either pass an object, or you could pass a function So in
   Think-Twice's example, an object is passed as an updater

   ```
   this.setState({ numbers: nums } //updater, () => {
           console.log(this.state.numbers); //this will print the updated value here
     });
   ```

   When a function is used as an updater (in your setNum function you
   already do that), the callback function can be utilized like below

   ```
   if (!this.state.numbers.includes(num)) {
         this.setState(
           prevState => ({
             numbers: [...prevState.numbers, num]
           }),
           () => {
             console.log("state logged inside if", this.state.numbers);
           }
         );
       }
   ```

Your current implementation and communication structure seems fine. It is actually called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) which is recommended also by official documentation.
Basically you store the state of array numbers in a parent component (which can be considered as the source of truth) and you pass the method that changes the state as a prop to it's child component.

In the codesandbox link I provided, the functionalities works the way I expect (at least this is what I expect from your code)

Answer (score 1):

Basically setState is asynchronous in React. When you modify a value using setState you will be able to see the updated value only in render. But to see updated state value immediately you need to do something like below

```
  this.setState({ numbers: nums }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.numbers); //this will print the updated value here
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get the wanted result of having the this.state.numbers updating properly. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I have two state change cases in the setNum function. How to change the one with prevState? I'm kinda new to React.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t understand your question. Can you please elaborate but more

Comment: What I want is to be able to add / remove numbers from the state array when clicking on the Button. The console.log is just a way to see the state, it's secondary. I have updated the question text to make it more clear. Sorry for the confusion.